# Whats wrong with my with strlen and substr PHP

Tags: php

I created a session called product_ .
When i click in my add to cart button, my

`$_SESSION['product_' . $_GET['add']]` 
will be like this product_171
the **171** is the id from a product that i have.
I printed out my query to see what's going on and my item_id is not echoing 171
it's sendind  **17** not **171**.
i tryed to change the numbers but it didn't work.

this is my code.

```
function cart(){
    global $conn;
    foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if($value > 0){

        if(substr($name, 0, 8 ) == "product_"){
            $length = strlen($name -8);
            $item_id = substr($name, 8 , $length);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM gallery2 WHERE id =".escape_string($item_id)."";
    print_r($name); echo' <strong>this is the name</strong></br>';
    print_r($item_id); echo'  <strong>this is the id without the name -product_</strong></br>';...
```

this is what i'm getting

**product_171 this is the name**

**17 this is the id without the name -product_**
why im not getting my full id?

Comment: ` strlen($name -8);` fix the typo and run again  `strlen($name) - 8;`

Comment: Different question: Why do you first add something, if you then have to remove it again for the value to be usable? Either use the id alone to identify the entry in the session (`$_SESSION['products'][id]`), or store it as an additional property inside the data structure that represents one product.

Comment: i learned from a class in [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/php-for-beginners-how-to-build-an-ecommerce-store/) and i learned that way

Comment: @Proger_Cbsk thx so much man it worked fine. Now answer the question, so i can select your answer as the solution.

Comment: Nah it's fine :) typo fixing isnt really the goal of  stackoverflow !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece of code where you check the string length is wrong:

```
if(substr($name, 0, 8 ) == "product_"){
        $length = strlen($name -8);
        $item_id = substr($name, 8 , $length);
...
```

You are checking strlen of `$name - 8`, and `$name - 8` is equal to `-8`, that have 2 characters, so it will always get 2 characters.

The `-8` should be out of the `strlen()` function:

```
if(substr($name, 0, 8 ) == "product_"){
        $length = strlen($name) - 8;
        $item_id = substr($name, 8 , $length);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode to get the id.

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    $data = explode("_", $name);
    $item_id = $data[1];
    ...
```